# Blackberry signature tool - invalid private key

Tags: blackberry, key, private, signature

A couple of months after installing successfully the BlackBerry signature key for signing my application, I have lost my private key. How can I retrieve it?

I have already sent an email to BlackBerry developers' support, but they're really slow in replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search your hard-drive or trash-bin for sigtool.*  :

You need to find sigtool.csk and sigtool.db.  If you can find these files you can copy them to your Components\bin folder.  For example:
C:\eclipses\BB1.1.2\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\bin
Or you can use the Import Key Feature of the Blackberry Plugin and point it to these files.

If you can't find these files, then you need TechSupport to resend you the three CSI files for creating your keys.  Note, after you create a key-set with these csi files they are useless, so you can't use them to recreate new keys later.

I suggest backing up the sigtool files after you find/recreate them.

Good Luck mate!